# How to get the id of a radio button in Java?

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, radio-button

I've created pragmatically 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. How can i get the Id of the radio buttons? Very important, i dont't want to use setOnCheckedChangeListener. Here is my code.

```
    radioGroup = new RadioGroup[5];
    answer = new RadioButton[4];
    int i = 0;
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
        radioGroup[i].setId(i);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
                answer[j].setId(j);
                radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);

        answer[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int checkedRadioButtonId = v.getId();
                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
                if (checkedRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checkbox" + checkedRadioButtonId  + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        i++;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what issue getting using current code?

Comment: The error is: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alexm.iq_test_final/com.example.alexm.iq_test_final.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4`

Comment: Your array is too small for what you are trying to fill it with. Increase the size of answer to 5 or decrease your population. Your issue is right in the error. 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in log :

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4

Because answer Array is size of `j`  instead of `i`, so move RadioButton click listener inside for loop:

```
for (Answer an : answers) {
  if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
       answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
         ...your code here...      
        answer[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your code here...
             }
        });
         j++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. This is the error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioGroup cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton`. What can be done?

Comment: @AlexM.: at which line getting it? please share latest code and full log

Comment: This is my code: [link](http://gogo.ro/14.png) and this is the error: [link](http://gogo.ro/15.png)

Comment: @AlexM.: what is line number 119?

Comment: This is the line 119: `RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);`

Comment: @AlexM.: try it after declaring as `int j=i+100;`

Comment: But where to declare `int j=i+100;`?

Comment: @AlexM.: you what is issue?? issue is RadioGroup and RadioButton `id` is same so try it after replacing `int j = 0;` to `int j=i+100;`

Comment: I did this but no i have this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alexm.iq_test_final/com.example.alexm.iq_test_final.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=100`

Comment: This is the log: [link](http://gogo.ro/16.png)
Again, same error :(
`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alexm.iq_test_final/com.example.alexm.iq_test_final.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4`

Comment: Please take a look: [link](http://gogo.ro/17.png) Error: [link](http://gogo.ro/16.png)

Comment: Also error: [link](http://gogo.ro/18.png)
 `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4`

Comment: We tried with `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, with `setOnClickListener` and it wasn't working. If this way is not possible, is there another way to do that?

Comment: @AlexM.: no i think only one listener is possible

Comment: Which one? `setOnCheckedChangeListener` or `setOnClickListener `?